# js compare between variable and div text

Tags: javascript, html, string, string-comparison

I'm trying to compare value of text inside div (This is a sentence.) and text defined in js variable:

```
function isSame(){
s="This is a sentence."
    var text1 = $('#right').text();
    var t1 =  text1.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/\<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace('\t','');
    var s1 = s.replace(/ /g,'').replace(/&nbsp;/g, '').replace(/\<br\s*[\/]?>/gi, '').replace('\t','');
    console.log(s1+" VS "+ t1);
    if (t1 == s1){
        console.log("Same");
    } else {
        console.log("Not same...");
    }
}
```

All the .replace are because on console I had extra tabs in div (which has style in it) I had extra spaces. Console log shows:

```
Thisisasentence. VS 

Thisisasentence.

Not same...
```

What is it I'm missing?

Comment: It would be worth posting the HTML as well.

Comment: looks like there are two line breaks at the start of t1

Comment: @DBS html is:       <div id="right">This is a sentence. </div>

Comment: @Mark, I think I removed them after Rob's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of this entire regular expression, have you tried using the `trim()` method?

As stated in the [documentation for String.prototype.trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim), in MDN:

> The trim() method removes whitespace from both ends of a string. Whitespace in this context is all the whitespace characters (space, tab, no-break space, etc.) and all the line terminator characters (LF, CR, etc.).

I believe your code should then be reduced to:

```
function isSame() {
    var s = "This is a sentence.";
    var text1 = $('#right').text();

    console.log(s1 + " VS " + t1);
    if (text1.trim() === s1) {
        console.log("Same");
    } else {
        console.log("Not the same...");
    }
}
```

And the comparison would work as expected.

---

**Update:**

As already mentioned in further answers by [Ysharp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1409653/ysharp) and [Rob Brander](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4821374/rob-brander), you could increment your regular expression by expanding it to other match new lines and carriage return elements. That would change your current regex by adding a `\s+` matcher to it, resulting in:

```
replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regular expressions look like they're trying to replace any whitespace characters.  I would suggest using \s as part of your regular expression, because that looks for all permutations of whitespace.

Your two strings are not equal because there is a newline before and after the phrase.  You could try replacing just the new lines with .replace('\n', '')

Comment: Hi Rob, thanks for the \s and \n suggestion. Console now shows both of them in same line, however it's still showing Not  same.

Answer (score 0):

You tried to get rid of whitespace using

```
replace(/ /g, '')
```

but as others pointed out, this is not sufficient to get rid of carriage returns and/or newlines.

Try this instead:

```
replace(/\s+/g, '')
```

which will take care of stripping out all of the '\t', '\n', etc, everywhere in the strings it is applied to.

'HTH,

Comment: Thank you, does work but ended up using trim, wish I could vote 2 correct answers.